# Why GUI Software Update App shows more updates than apt list --upgradable?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

Sometimes I notice that GUI Software Update App shows more updates than apt list --upgradable. Could You help me and say why?

todays list of updates

[image: img_list_of_updates]

example of package only in apt console

[image: img_apt_console]

Comment: Did you compare the two lists to figure out *exactly* which packages were excluded?

Comment: I think that this is because some packages are noted as "Installed version: None". For example linux-headers-5.8.0-63-generic:, linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-63: linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-63-generic: and  linux-modules-5.8.0-63-generic:

Comment: I have exactly the same question and still no answer!